# Apply math.round into scala language

Tags: scala

Instead of using this approach:

```
a.map(100 * _.answer.toFloat).map(_.toInt + "%").getOrElse("")
```

How can I apply math.round approach in above code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you mean, you want to round instead of use `toInt`, which just cuts off the decimals? Then just use `round` instead of `toInt`:

```
a.map(100 * _.answer.toFloat).map(_.round + "%").getOrElse("")
```

Answer (score 1):

Arguably a comment, but I needed to include code...

Jesper's answer can be improved by collapsing the double-map, and extracting the method to calculate a percent string:

```
def percentStr(x: Float) = (100*x).round.toString + "%"

a.map(x => percentStr(x.answer.toFloat)).getOrElse("")
```